# How does C recognize macro tokens as arguments

Tags: c

```
#define function(in) in+1 
int main(void) 
{ 
    printf("%d\n",function(1));
    return 0; 
}
```

The above is correctly preprocessed to :

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n",1+1);
    return 0;
}
```

However, if the macro `in+1` is changed to `in_1`, the preprocessor will not do the argument replacement correctly and will end up with this:

```
printf("%d\n",in_1);
```

What are the list of tokens the preprocessor can correctly separate and insert the argument? (like the + sign)

Comment: Shouldn't the second one evaluated to `1_1`, not `in_1`

Comment: @smac89 no it shouldn't, OP question is what the difference is between in_1 and in+1 .

Comment: @M.M you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** The replacement done by preprocessor is not simple text substitution. In your case, the argument must be an identifier, and it can only replace the identical identifiers.

---

The related form of preprocessing is

```
#define identifier(identifier-list) token-sequence
```

In order for the replacement to take place, the identifiers in the `identifier-list` and the tokens in the `token-sequence` must be identical in the token sense, according to C's tokenization rule (the rule to parse stream into tokens).

If you agree with the fact that

1. in C `in` and `in_1` are two different identifiers (and C cannot relate one to the other), while
2. `in+1` is not an identifier but a sequence of three tokens:

   (1) identifier `in`,

   (2) operator `+`, and

   (3) integer constant `1`,

then your question is clear: `in` and `in_1` are just two identifiers between which C does not see any relationship, and cannot do the replacement as you wish.

---

**Reference 1:** In C, there are six classes of tokens:

(1) identifiers (e.g. `in`)

(2) keywords (e.g. `if`)

(3) constants (e.g. `1`)

(4) string literals (e.g. `"Hello"`)

(5) operators (e.g. `+`)

(6) other separators (e.g. `;`)

**Reference 2:** In C, an **identifier** is a sequence of letters (including `_`) and digits (the first one cannot be a digit).

**Reference 3:** The tokenization rule:

> ... the next token is the longest string of characters that could constitute a token.

This is to say, when reading `in+1`, the compiler will read all the way to `+`, and knows that `in` is an identifier. But in the case of `in_1`, the compiler will read all the way to the white space after it, and deems `in_1` as an identifier.

*All references from the Reference Manual from K&R's The C Programming Language. Language evolved but they capture the essence.*

Answer (score 1):

See the C11 standard section 6.4 for the tokenization grammar .

The relevant token type here is *identifier*, which is defined as any sequence of letters or digits that doesn't start with a digit; also there can be `\u` codes and other implementation-defined characters in an identifier.

Due to the "maximal munch" principle of tokenization, character sequence `in+1` is tokenized as `in` `+` `1`   (not `i` `n` `+` `1`).

Answer (score 0):

if you want in_1, use two hashes....

```cpp
#define function(in) in ## _1
```

So...

```cpp
function(dave)   --> dave_1
function(phil)   --> phil_1
```

And for completeness, you can also use a single hash to turn the arg into a text string.

```cpp
#define function(in) printf(#in "\n");
```

Comment: no no my question is, how does the preprocessor recognize the + sign as a separator but not the _ sign. what other sign are similarly recognizable?

Comment: Uhm. I just gave you the answer ?
You have to remember that '_' is a valid identifier. So the preprocessor does not see in_1 as being in with _1 appended. It sees it as an entirely new identifier. What you are aiming to do is concatenate the identifier 'in' with something else. + is not a valid identifier. It's an operator.

Comment: Identifiers can start with a character, or an underscore. After the first character, numbers may also be used. That's it. Those are the entire rules.